# localhost says please enter valid length

Tags: mysql

I have done the Setup database in localhost PHPMyadmin.
when I submit a form via PHP it throw error like **please enter valid length**
What is the problem with this query?
Please look into the query and help.

```
    CREATE TABLE `test`.`test`
  (
     `id`          INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
     `oname`       VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     `cname`       VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     `cphone`      VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     `cemail`      VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     `tplot`       VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     `registerno`  VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     `registerdoc` TEXT NOT NULL,
     `tpscheme`    INT NOT NULL,
     `tpnumber`    INT NOT NULL,
     `spnumber`    INT NOT NULL,
     `area`        VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     `plotarea`    INT NOT NULL,
     `direction`   VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     `roads`       VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     `r1w`         VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     `r2w`         VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     `r3w`         VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     `r4w`         VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     `r1d`         VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     `r2d`         VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     `r3d`         VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     `r4d`         VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     `zoning`      INT NOT NULL,
     `zoningdoc`   INT NOT NULL,
     `benefit`     VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     `natureplot`  VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     `deduction`   VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     `howmuch`     INT NOT NULL,
     `allsidedoc`  VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     `diagonaldoc` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     `totalmem`    INT NOT NULL,
     `flatgiven`   INT NOT NULL,
     `fun`         VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     `fun`         VARCHAR NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  )
engine = innodb;
```

Comment: Please provide some details on what is the problem (not only in the title), e.g. exact error message and how did you try to resolve it. Please also format code as code.

Comment: Note that any time you find yourself with enumerated columns (above, say, 2) you can be certain that your design is suboptimal. These should be split out as rows in a separate table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must assign a length to varchar datatype  eg:  VARCHAR(255)

```
CREATE TABLE `mainland`.`mainland1` ( 
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    `oname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
    `cname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `cphone` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `cemail` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `tplot` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `registerno` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `registerdoc` TEXT NOT NULL , 
    `tpscheme` INT NOT NULL , 
    `tpnumber` INT NOT NULL , 
    `spnumber` INT NOT NULL , 
    `area` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `plotarea` INT NOT NULL , 
    `direction` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `roads` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `r1w` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `r2w` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `r3w` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `r4w` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `r1d` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `r2d` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `r3d` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `r4d` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `zoning` INT NOT NULL , 
    `zoningdoc` INT NOT NULL , 
    `benefit` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `natureplot` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `deduction` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `howmuch` INT NOT NULL , 
    `allsidedoc` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `diagonaldoc` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `totalmem` INT NOT NULL ,
     `flatgiven` INT NOT NULL , 
     `fun` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
     `fun` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 2):

The max length of a VARCHAR is not dynamic, it is fixed and therefore has to be specified.
http://sqlines.com/mysql/datatypes/varchar